Is there a way to get rid of voltage clippings across a load, so that the voltage output waveform across it is a sine wave?
So, we've been assigned to simulate a circuit to drive an 8ohm 0.25 watts speaker/load with a 3V voltage supply (DC) and a test input of 300mV peak-to-peak, 1kHz zero-offset sine-wave. (No additional supply must be used and only passive components are allowed). There should be a voltage gain of 7.
I made a simulation (though I'm not sure if it meets the requirements) but the problem is that the voltage output waveform across the load is clipped. I want to remove the clippings but I don't know how to. We're not allowed to use an inductor, so I can't make a filter for it. I'd be glad to read any suggestion. Thanks.
Here's the circuit that I made. I uploaded 2 images. One of it shows the circuit diagram that I made, the other shows the waveform of the input voltage (orange) and the output voltage (red). As you can see, the output voltage is clipped and I've been trying to remove that clipping but I can't and I don't know how to. Please help
PS. All the resistors have a 0.25W power rating (including the load), except for the 10 ohm resistors, nearest to the load, which has a 1W power rating. While the capacitors have a 50V voltage rating (Pk).

Welcome!  What would help us to help you:

A list of the requirements your circuit has to meet.  And include any constraints, eg: not allowed to use op-amps.  2. The waveforms (or other results) that clearly show why you think the requirements are not met.  Use arrows and text to clearly show the features you want us to see.


What is the application?  Example: is this (a) an audio amplifier, or is it (b) a signal detector?   For (a) the output has to be a good replica of the input with low distortion.  For (b) the output at the speaker can be anything, it only has to provide an indication that the "test input" signal has been detected, it does not have to replicate test signal with low distortion.

A few of thought/comments/questions here:
#1.
You mentioned that the input is 300mV peak-to-peak, sinewave, 1kHz. Gain is 7.
That means the output voltage is 2.1V peak-to-peak (1.05V peak) across an 8Ω load. This is a peak power of 138mW, average power of 68.9mW.
This should be quite easy to do with an op-amp that has rail-to-rail output capability. Are you permitted to use op-amps?

Question #2.
2.1V peak-to-peak from a 3.0V supply voltage leaves only 0.9V as the "headroom". Are you sure the power supply voltage is 3.0V and not 3.3V? If it is 3.3V, then the headroom increases to 1.2V which makes it easier to design the output stage.

Question #3.
Which of the following electronic building blocks have you studied:  A. Differential pair. B. Common-emitter amplifier with active collector load. C. Current sources & sinks. D. Voltage (emitter / source) follower.

Question #4.
Are you permitted to build a boost converter to boost the 3.0V up to, say, 5V?

Hi, thank you for noticing!

so, about the first question, the requirements only states that there should be an implementation of small voltage gain which is 7, with no noticeable distortion. only passive components are allowed as well as BJTs, and diodes. Inductors and transformers are not allowed. 3V shall be the voltage supply and a test input of 300mV peak-to-peak, 1kHz zero-offset sine-wave. Another/additional supply must not be used. lastly, the waveform across the speaker must be a full sine-wave. That's all the requirement states.

The circuit diagram is my own design so I'm not sure if it's correct or not. We've already discussed about Common-emitter amplifier, voltage follower but to tell you the truth, I having a hard time understanding it. That's why I'm asking for help.

Op-amp is an active component while boost converter uses inductor, so both is not allowed

Btw, I've edited my post and added an image which shows the behaviors of the input and output voltage waveform.

Oh, if you have a suggestion about the circuit diagram (even if it's entirely different from mine) I would like to know it. Thanks again

Only passive elements are allowed? Then you can't do an amplifier, which requires active elements.

BJTs are allowed, so I think we can use transistors

If you're allowed BJTs, you can boost the input voltage. Just use a charge pump. But know that BJTs are active elements!

Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I'll try to to execute your suggestion but I'm not really sure if I can do it properly because I really don't know a lot of things about charge pump. So I guess I'll have to study it first. But anyway, thanks

Firstly, let's list out the requirements of the circuit (amplifier):



#
Parameter
Value
Comment




1
Supply voltage
Confirmed as 3.0VDC, not 3.3V.
Magnetic components, eg: inductor, are not permitted, so using a boost converted to increase the voltage for the amplifier is not permitted.


2
Test signal
300mV peak-to-peak, sinewave, 1kHz.
nil


3
Voltage Gain
7.0
nil


4
Output
2.1V peak-to-peak (1.05V peak) across an 8Ω load, without noticeable distortion.
This is an output current of 263mA p-p, or 131mA peak; which represents an output power of 138mW peak, average power of 68.9mW


5
Input Impedance
Not mentioned.
Assume 100kΩ @ test signal


6
Low F -3dB
Not mentioned.
Assume <100Hz


7
High F -3dB
Not mentioned.
Assume > 20kHz



.
Permitted and Not-Permitted Components:



Permitted
Not Permitted




BJTs, diodes, resistors, capacitors.
Op-amps, magnetic components of any kind (transformers, inductors), MOSFETs, JFETs.



.
Comments:
All these requirements seem reasonable, the only one to pose a challenge is requirement #4.  The output shall be 2.1V peak-to-peak from a 3.0V supply voltage, which leaves only 0.9V as the "headroom".  The usual common-collector (emitter-follower) output stage in push-pull configuration cannot go closer than 0.7V to  each supply rail, hence it requires a "headroom" of at least 1.4V, ie: the maximum peak-to-peak output that is possible is:
(Vcc - 1.4V) = ( 3.0V - 1.4V ) = 1.6V p-p.
In practice, the maximum voltage swing that will be possible will be somewhat less than this, due to the limits of the stages that drive the output stage.
For an explanation of unity-gain buffer stages (emitter-follower push-pull), refer:
Unity Gain Amplifier Purpose
Therefore, I would recommend using two identical amplifiers configured in a bridged arrangement.  Each amplifier has a standard push-pull voltage follower output stage that is capable of swinging 1.2V peak-to-peak from a 3V supply; in bridge configuration, the voltage across the load doubles to 2.4V peak-to-peak, which meets the requirements.  The other benefit is that this configuration eliminates the large dc-blocking capacitor at the output that is required for non-bridged arrangements.
This post here will provide some guidance as to how to design an amplifier that meets your requirements:
Why am I getting heavy output distortion from a BJT amplifier when driving an 8 ohm load?
The specific heading related to your question:
1W Amplifier using Bridged Twin Amplifiers

Update
Another option is to use an output stage that can swing the output node very close to the supply rails.  This requires the output stage to be a common-emitter push-pull pair (or common-source for MOSFET), compared to the common-collector (common-drain) push-pull pair proposed previously.  Using small-signal BJTs (such as BC546/556), this stage may be able to swing to within 0.2V of the supply rail while sourcing/sinking ~150mA of current.  However, this configuration is far more difficult to control and requires a nuanced approach to biasing.
A post that provides a starting point for investigating this topic can be found here, refer to my answer there, and also the answer by @spehro-pefhany.
How does a common-emitter rail-to-rail opamp output stage work? Is there a discrete example?

can I ask for a circuit diagram design which would meet the said requirements. I want to compare it the circuit diagram that I made so that I will know which part of my diagram is wrong.

@archaeonred  The post I linked should be sufficient for you to determine a suitable circuit diagram.

As Fabio has pointed out, a 2.1V peak-to-peak output swing required from a 3V DC supply is a difficult spec to meet. His suggestion of two bridged amplifiers makes this spec far less difficult to meet - a good solution, but complex.
The circuit topology suggested in the question is reasonable too, but requires careful choice of DC bias. Its disadvantage is that a great deal of wasted power supply current is needed to obtain reasonably-low distortion of the sine wave. Since no spec has limited DC current drawn from that +3V supply, take advantage. Such an amplifier (if actually built) would require heat sink on the output transistor - a simulation doesn't burn fingers.
The distortion spec is ambiguous...(no noticeable distortion). By eye on an oscilloscope? By ear from the speaker? My trained ear could barely hear 0.5% distortion, more easily for higher harmonics. You might aim for a spec of 1% harmonic distortion, so that any harmonic is 40 dB below that 1 kHz signal.
Since that output transistor must operate within 0.9V of the DC supply, you might choose to boost its standing DC current by 2.1/0.9 ratio. If peak speaker current is 0.13125 A, then transistor current should be at least 0.3A. Give yourself a break, and use even more. R3 (below) will end up a good deal smaller than the 8 ohm load.
Try to find a power transistor for Q2 that remains linear at high current. Many have reduced current gain as collector current goes up. So you might look for one that can handle lots more current than you really need.
Take advantage that signal source of 1 kHz sine wave has no spec of source resistance, so assume it is zero, making voltage gain of Q1 a bit easier to set. Its collector resistance divided by emitter resistance will end up being close to the required gain of 7.
I have not shown DC biasing of Q1, since a DC offset of V1 could be used to set the proper point

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A better design might ask of Q1 for more gain, then apply over-all negative feedback from output-to-input to reduce gain back to 7. This makes meeting distortion spec easier.

can I ask for a circuit diagram design which would meet the said requirements. I want to compare it the circuit diagram that I made so that I will know which part of my diagram is wrong.

archaeon red: I'm sympathetic - had hoped to encourage you that your basic approach is good, and that a satisfactory result can be achieved. Please apply a little sweat-equity. Your Q2 emitter resistor is too large. Bias Q2 with more DC current. Q1 may need more DC current too to provide stiffer drive for Q2.

I'm sorry for the inconvenience, I've started learning amplifier applications just recently so I'm having a hard time comprehending the task given to us which is supposed easy. I've tried other suggestions like using only one stage for the circuit, but I always get stuck at the output voltage. In the circuit diagram that I made, I've already met the voltage gain of 7, but the only problem that I can't solve is the waveform of the voltage across the load which should be a full sine-wave but in my circuit, it is clippedcli

That's why I'm here asking for any suggestions that could help me remove the voltage clipping across the load. I'll try everyone's suggestions and see if I can make it work.
